pushing to an array throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 15, object is not extensible
I started learning typescript last week and I'm practising. in the app I'm building I'm having this error when pushing a new element to the array
here is my array and its type:
export type Users = {
  id: number;
  img: string;
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  createdAt: string;
  verified: boolean;
};


export const usersData: Users[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/8405873/pexels-photo-8405873.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1600&lazy=load",
    lastName: "Watson",
    firstName: "Joe",
    email: "joe@gmail.com",
    phone: "123 456 789",
    createdAt: "01.02.2024",
    verified: true,
  },];

where I'm pushing the new user:
function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
   const inputValues = Object.fromEntries(formData);

    const newUser:Omit<Users, "id" | "img" | "createdAt" | "verified">  = {...inputValues};
    

    
    // submit logic
    //.....
    addUser(newUser);

    // after submitting, close the modal
     onCloseModal(currentState => !currentState);
  }


export function addUser(user:Omit<Users, "id" | "img" | "createdAt" | "verified">) {
  const newUser = {...user, id: usersData.length, createdAt: "today",img: "/noavatar.png" , verified: false};
  usersData.push(newUser);
  console.log("new user", usersData[usersData.length - 1]);

  //console.log(Object.isExtensible(usersData)); //prints false
  //console.log(Object.isFrozen(usersData)); // prints true
  //console.log(Object.isSealed(usersData)); // prints true
}

what causes this error? I didn't use Object.freeze() or similar to it anywhere in my code to disable the ability to modify the array in my whole app. does this related to TypeScript ?
Edit:
I noticed a warning that might be helpful. it's in this line const newUser:Omit<Users, "id" | "img" | "createdAt" | "verified">  = {...inputValues}; that says:
Type '{ [k: string]: FormDataEntryValue; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<Users, "id" | "img" | "createdAt" | "verified">': lastName, firstName, email, phone


Are you using anything like redux toolkit? (Ie: how did you create your project?)

@NickParsons No I don't use Redux, the project was created using Vite if that is what you meant. I'm also using react-router-dom but I believe it has nothing to do with this error

Do you put usersData in state at all?

@NickParsons no I don't
